# getting dll from resource

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource

How to get the binary body from a file in resources?

I tried this:

```
byte[] bin = Properties.Resources.DllName;
StreamWriter writerDll = new StreamWriter("dll.dll");
writerDll.Write(bin);
writerDll.Close();
```

but I'm getting just first line of the file. How to fix this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: StreamWriter is for text.  Don't write code like this.  It won't work on your user's machine, UAC stops it.  A single .exe file with DLLs embedded in it is called setup.exe, create one with a Setup project.

Comment: Hans is right. One case where this *can* make sense though is if the DLL you've embedded is a .NET assembly that your application will utilize (think `Assembly.Load(byte[] rawAssembly)`) in which case you shouldn't be dumping it to disk anyway. Even still ILMerge is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

The first line does it all.
Remove the other lines.